# Value of second parameter of pygame.mask.set_at()

Tags: pygame

I cant seem to figure out the importance of the value of the second parameter of the `pygame.mask.set_at()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pygame.mask.set_at()` is used to set single bits of the mask to `0` or `1` which you pass as the `value` argument.